# What resolution in sitemap.xml image attribute?

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search

I'm just creating a sitemap for my page and I found these aspects for creating it on Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668

There is a attribute for images, but my question is: Does anyone know what kind of image site I have to put there? There is a big image on the page and should I include the full resolution path or a path to a thumbnail?

Anyone got experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

The full image is the content. The thumbnail is metadata describing the image. Therefore, it should be the full image.

(Assuming you want it to be indexed by image search engines, if you don't really care, then omit it entirely).